# Scale-agnostic, differentiable, co-planarity measure

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

I am looking for an (almost everywhere) differentiable function $f(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$ that given four points will give me a scale-agnostic measure for co-planarity. It is zero if the four points lie on the same plane and positive otherwise. Scale-agnostic means that, when I uniformly scale all points the planarity measure will return the same.

I came up with something that is quite complex and not easy to optimize. Define $u=p_2-p_1$, $v=p_3-p_1$, $w=p_4-p_1$. Then the planarity measure is:

$$\frac{\left[(u \times v) \cdot w \right]^{2}}{\left(||u \times v||^{2} ||w||^{2} \right)}$$

The numerator is simply (the square of) the volume of the tetrahedron defined by the four points, and the denominator is a normalizing factor that makes this measure become simply the cosine of an angle. Because angles do not changed under uniform scale, this function satisfies all my requirements.

Does anybody know of something simpler?

Alex.